# How does for-each loop with two static methods in JAVA?

Tags: java, arraylist, foreach, static-methods

Things I can't grasp is how printAL(a) initiates and how does for-each run here. There are 4 printAL(a)'s and code outcome has 4 new lines, so what for-each is each-ing (the whole static void main method?)?

```java
import java.util.*;

public class ArrayListMagnet {
        
    public static void main (String [] args) {
        ArrayList<String> a = new ArrayList<String>();
        a.add(0, "zero");
        a.add(1, "one");
        a.add(2, "two");
        a.add(3, "three");
        printAL(a); 
        if (a.contains("three")) {
            a.add("four");
        }
        a.remove(2);
        printAL(a);
        if (a.indexOf("four") != 4){
            a.add(4, "4.2");
        }
        printAL(a);
        if (a.contains ("two")) {
            a.add("2.2");
        }
        printAL(a);
    }
    
    public static void printAL(ArrayList<String> al) {
        for (String element : al) {
            System.out.print(element + " ");
        }
        System.out.println(" ");
    }   
}
```

Comment: There's no magic, it is printing all array list elements ([a] in this case) with space between them, and after printing all of them printing a new line. So, 4 method invocation - 4 new lines.

Comment: It is not clear to me what your question means ("what for-each is each-ing").  Are you getting an unexpected result?

Comment: Yeah thanks fellas, I get expected result just wanted to understand how foreach is run by JVM. I also kinda missed that creates elements named elements maybe confusion there. Anyhow wanted to hear in different words to understand fully, how this poece runs. 
I also understand that this foreach is advanced and equivalent for it would be:
`for (int i = 0; i < al.size(); i++) {
   String element = al.get(i);
   System.out.print(element + “ “);
}`